# LottieView animation Is not display?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, lottie

I'm using React Native and I have two lottieview animations when I put them inside condition both lottieview animation are not working at all but if I remove the condition the lottieview works

success screen

```
const Success = ({navigation}) => {

  const [ lottiFinished, setLottiFinished ] = useState(false)

  const onAnimationFinish = () => {

       setLottiFinished(true)
       setTimeout(()=>{
       navigation.navigate('Delivery')
    },4000)
  }
     

    return (
        <View style = {{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
        }}>
     {
      !lottiFinished ?

      //////====First lottiView to display=====////
      <LottieView 
           source={images.progress}
           autoPlay
           loop={false}
           onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
           style={{
            height:60,
            width:100
           }}
      
      />
      :
      ////=====second lottiView to display after first one=====////
      <View style={{
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
       }}>
           
          <LottieView
            autoPlay
            loop={false} 
            source={images.done}
            style={{height:200,width:"60%"}}
      />

           <Text>Congratulations!</Text>
           <Text>Payment was successfully made</Text>
         </View>
     }
        </View>
    )
}
```

what I want is that I wanna the first lottieview display and then the second one after that the delivery screen comes later but What I can see only screen empty with only text show up no animation with it for 4 sec then the delivery screen show up. anyone can help, I'm so grateful